# Минимальная строка, содержащая строки из набора

Tags: python, алгоритм, строки

Задача состоит в том, чтобы составить такую строку минимальной длины, которая будет содержать все строки заданного множества.
Например: для 00 01 10 11 результат будет 00110 (а не 00011011, если просто расставить заданные числа по порядку).

Конкретно нужно расставлять числа заданной длины в десятичной и двоичной системе счисления.

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы вам подали идею или материал для изучения или же, чтобы решили за вас? В последнем случае вопрос точно жестко заминисуют.

Comment: Материал для изучения, конечно же)

Comment: Я вижу, на англоязычном сайте не разобрались с сутью вашего вопроса =)

Comment: Была подобная тема [PHP][http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488339/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA/490527#490527]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем случае задача имеет довольно сложное решение, но начать изучение материала можно с ознакомления с графом (и последовательностями) де Брёйна.

---

Вот, например, граф для всех бинарных последовательностей длины 4:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
([изображение взято с википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence#/media/File:De_bruijn_graph-for_binary_sequence_of_order_4.svg))

Строится он следующим образом (на примере последовательностей длины 4):

1. Берутся все встречающиеся подпоследовательности длины 3, они будут вершинами графа.
2. Далее для каждой последовательности длины четыре из вершины префикса проводится ребро в вершину-суффикс. На ребре запоминаем последний символ последовательности. Например, последовательность 1110 соединит вершину 111 с вершиной 110, на ребре пишем 0.
3. Находим эйлеров цикл и записываем соответствующую ему последовательность символов-переходов по рёбрам (не забываем обходить и петли).
   Например, выполним обход следующим образом: 100 - 000 - 000 - 001 - 010 - 100 - 001 - 011 - 111 - 111 - 110 - 101 - 010 - 101 - 011 - 110 - 100, что соответствует циклической последовательности 0010011110101100, в которой действительно встречаются все бинарные строки длины четыре.

---

Для генерации не циклической строки нужно немного изменить исходный алгоритм.

Comment: красивый рисунок ;) +1

Comment: @MichaelPak Это с википедии (добавлю пометку)